# Nuxt js application freezing without any reason

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have `Navigation` component in my nuxt application and it use window object and I know it has problem with SSR.

I have imported this component in default layout. But I commented this component in `default.vue` layout, but still gives error and freezing!

error message:

```
window is not defined
```

I'm confused.

Comment: Could you share the webpack config?

Comment: @T.Short this is my nuxt.config.js https://jsfiddle.net/gojw5e0k/

Comment: You probably are using a plugin that uses `window` object, try to comment plugins in your config one by one and check if  the error still exists.

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki https://jsfiddle.net/gojw5e0k/ as you see, i don't used any special plugin/module that use window object.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this:

```
if (process.client) {
// put your code that should be executed on the client side here
}
```

Comment: as i told before, i commented my code. but it still gives error.is it caching?

Comment: did you try to wrap your component in an `<client-only>` tag?

Comment: i removed my Navigation component from default.vue layout, but still gives error.